# time offset in blender compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, image

I want to subtract the current frame from a previous frame, I have a image sequence and I want blender to subtract the current frame from the frame with an offset of -4. If I am on frame 5 so blender will subtract and use frame 1.

Comment: You can use the offset of the image sequence node

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image node has an offset option which does exactly this:

[image]